# How to implement play or pause a flash?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, flash, cocoa, webkit

I used a webkit to show a flash , but now I want to add a play button and control the flash , How to do ? thank you very much!

Comment: Your tags make this very confusing.  Are you using a webkit control, and trying to pause a flash video with Objective C, or are you using Client-Side JS to do it... or do you want to use actionscript[2,3?] to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can exchange data between flash an javascript using ExternalInterface.
Check this link for more info:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html